# Post/Get requests using HttpClient implementation

Tags: c#, bots, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to make a bot for a browser game, i'm really passionate about this project and i have thought about the model and everything but when i wanted to actually implement it i got lost, i know it's all about post/get requests and i watched the HTTP headers using firefox plugin and i kinda get the idea of how things works when i make an action in the game.

my question is, how can i make an HTTP post request with given info ( username + password to star with ) , that logs me into the game, and then get info ( resources for instance ) of the first page maybe?

if i can just get past that point i'll progress, i'm really stuck.

thanks.

Comment: Have you checked `HttpClient`? Here are two links that you could start with `HttpClient`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client and https://www.dotnetperls.com/httpclient.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use fiddler(http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture all the requests and then you could try to do the same using HttpClient or even HttpRequest.

Your bot should be able to make the same requests to the server as your browser do.